# How to join tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

parts:

> ```
> +-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
> +-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
> +-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> +----+
> | id |
> +----+
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> +----+
> ```

parts_partid:

> ```
> +-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
> | Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
> +-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
> | part_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
> | partid_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
> +-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
> +---------+-----------+
> | part_id | partid_id |
> +---------+-----------+
> |       1 |         1 |
> |       1 |         2 |
> |       1 |         3 |
> |       2 |         1 |
> |       2 |         4 |
> |       2 |         5 |
> |       3 |         6 |
> |       3 |         7 |
> |       3 |         8 |
> +---------+-----------+
> ```

partid:

> ```
> +-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
> +-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
> | key   | varchar(50)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
> | value | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
> +-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> +----+-----+-------+
> | id | key | value |
> +----+-----+-------+
> |  1 | l   | foo   |
> |  2 | p   | bar   |
> |  3 | s   | baz   |
> |  4 | l   | 3     |
> |  5 | p   | 5     |
> |  6 | s   | r     |
> |  7 | l   | rr    |
> |  8 | l   | rrr   |
> +----+-----+-------+
> ```

Basically each part consists of arbitrary part-ids. e.g. part #1 has l = 'foo', p = 'bar' and s = 'baz'.

If I want to search for all parts which have l = 'foo' I use this join

```
SELECT p.id FROM parts AS p
INNER JOIN parts_partid ppi ON ppi.part_id = p.id
INNER JOIN partid pi ON ppi.partid_id = pi.id
WHERE pi.key = 'l' AND pi.value = 'foo';
```

Which gives me part #1 and #2.

Now I want to search for all parts which have l = 'foo' **and** p = '5' (which should result in only part #2). How can I do this?

Comment: What RDBMS you are using??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    p.id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pi.Key = 'l' THEN value END) AS l,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pi.Key = 'p' THEN value END) AS p,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pi.Key = 's' THEN value END) AS s
  FROM parts AS p
  INNER JOIN parts_partid ppi ON ppi.part_id = p.id
  INNER JOIN partid pi ON ppi.partid_id = pi.id
  GROUP BY p.id
) AS t
WHERE l = 'foo' 
  AND p = 5;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b799c/11)

This will give you only the part2:

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b799c/11/0)**:

```
| ID |
------
|  2 |
```

---

The idea behind this query, is the subquery, which will *pivot* the keys' values into columns; it will give you those keys for each id as columns headers:

```
| ID |   L |      P |      S |
------------------------------
|  1 | foo |    bar |    baz |
|  2 | foo |      5 | (null) |
|  3 | rrr | (null) |      r |
```

Then in the outer query you can filter on the values of these columns.

Comment: @user2210830 - So does it work fine for you? If so try to accept it, by checking the mark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
SELECT p.id FROM parts AS p
INNER JOIN parts_partid ppi ON ppi.part_id = p.id
INNER JOIN partid pi ON ppi.partid_id = pi.id
WHERE (pi.key = 'l' AND pi.value = 'foo')
or    (pi.key ='p' and pi.value = '5')
```

Comment: I don't think that workds. Because it is possible that a parrt with p=5 exists which doesn't have l=foo. I want both, but if I "AND" everything together I get nothing.

Comment: so u can use "OR" Operator.